# Display all enums from an EMF model in a CheckBoxTable ?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf

I am trying to display a CheckBoxTable in an Eclipse page which enables the user to select any one of a number of items - the items that are available come from an EMF model and are enums.

I've got the content provider and the label provider set up correctly (I think) but I can't figure what to use to set the input in order to display the full list of enums.

So say my model has an enum called MyEnum which has values of ONE, TWO and THREE - I want to be able to display all three of those enums to the user as check boxes.

I need to call setInput(...) on the viewer but what do I pass into it to get those enums?

Comment: You need to return the enum list from your content provider. The viewer doesn't do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've never done it for a `CheckboxTableViewer`, I have set an `EEnum` as the source of values for other `StructuredViewer` classes like `ComboViewer`. What I did was create a custom `IStructuredContentProvider` that is a subclass of `ArrayList` and takes the `EEnum` as a constructor argument (call this class `EEnumContentProvider`). In the constructor, I iterate over the `EEnum`'s `getELiterals()` and call `add()` on each of their `getInstance()` values. Like this:

```
public EEnumContentProvider(EEnum source) {
    List<EEnumLiteral> literals = source.getELiterals();
    for (EEnumLiteral aLiteral : literals) {
        add(aLiteral.getInstance());
    }
}
```

You can easily implement `IStructuredContentProvider.getElements(Object)` by using returning the result of `toArray()` and you don't care about `IContentProvider.setInput()` because the contents aren't based on the input, they're static.

Then you can set an instance of `EEnumContentProvider` as the content provider for the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to get the literals and add them to the control as follows:

```
/* Populate the Combo Box with the Literals */    
EEnum cFEnum = Package.Literals.LITERAL_ENUMERATION;
/* 
 * Add an EMPTY item value so that the user can disable the specific 
 * feature 
 */
this.cmbNames.add( EMPTY_STRING );

/*
 * Add the  Enumeration Literals to the 
 * appropriate SWT Combo widget.
 */
for (int i=0; i<cFEnum.getELiterals().size(); i++){         
  this.cmbNames.add( cFEnum.getEEnumLiteral( i ).toString() );
}
cFEnum = null;


String[] sortedTypes = this.cmbNames.getItems();
Arrays.sort( sortedTypes );
this.cmbNames.setItems( sortedTypes );
```